# Remove an element and shift the remaining elements to the left

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java programming. I want to know how to shift the remaining elements after deleting the chosen element. The problem is that the end of index shows the same element from the previous index of last. I just want the output just like: `{1, 44, 5, 34, 8, 10, 11, 100, 0, 11, 0}`.

My actual output is: `{1, 44, 5, 34, 8, 10, 11, 100, 0, 11, 11}`.

I will show you my actual code. I don't need ArrayList or List to work. I want to test it without them.

```
for (int i = indexToDelete; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i+1];
        size--;
    }
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("The element at index " + i + ": " + array[i]);
} //END for()            
System.out.println(size);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly remove the item from the array that's already allocated. You have 2 options:

1. `array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length - 1);` - This created a copy in place removing the last element
2. Convert to an array list and call the remove method.

Sample of #1:

```
    int[] array = {1,2,3};
    int indexToDelete = 1;
    for (int i = indexToDelete; i < array.length-1; i++) {
         array[i] = array[i+1];
    }
    array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("The element at index " + i + ": " + array[i]);
    }
```

Output:

```
The element at index 0: 1
The element at index 1: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the last element to zero you should set the last element to zero:

```
for (int i = indexToDelete; i < array.length-1; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i+1];
    size--;
}
array[array.length-1] = 0;
```

Probably you should check if your array actually contains any elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of array without the last element:

```
array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep another `int` variable to store the current size of the array (after elements are deleted).

Or, you could delete an element from the end and use [`Arrays.copyOf(int \[\], int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int))

Most importantly, no matter which of the two approaches you use, if you are deleting an element from the middle you could consider copying the last element to the position of the deleted element, rather than shifting all subsequent elements by 1. If this works for you then it would be vastly more efficient.